# How to get response from url in json for android and than after reponse i want to parse it

Tags: android, exception

I am trying to fetch data from thingspeak api and I am taking Input for channel id and passing it on URL. But I have to check if the url is responding or not, if it is responding than go ahead with the code else user have to change channel id.

Error I  am getting is  **'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference**

and

**W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/497971/feeds.json?results=1**

This is invalid url if I change it to

**https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/497970/feeds.json?results=1**

This will work

Code I am trying is

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView a, b;
    String result = "";
    String field1,field2,field3;
    private int count = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        a = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a);
        b = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.b);

        new CountDownTimer(100000, 10000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
                task.execute("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/497970/feeds.json?results=1");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        }.start();
    }

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            URL url;
            result = "";
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                int data = reader.read();
                while (data != -1) {
                    char current = (char) data;
                    result += current;
                    data = reader.read();
                }
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            search(result);
        }

        public void search(String result) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONObject fieldinfo = jsonObject.getJSONObject("channel");

                String ff1 =  fieldinfo.optString("field1","No Value");
                String ff2 = fieldinfo.optString("field2","No Value");

                JSONArray weatherInfo = jsonObject.getJSONArray("feeds");

                JSONObject legsobject = weatherInfo.getJSONObject(0);
                  field1 = legsobject.getString("field1");
                  field2 = legsobject.getString("field2");

                a.setText(ff1);

                c.setText(field1);

            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the Image of error**

[image: **Here is the Image of error**]

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are not taking into account that **HTTP connections sometimes do fail, like in this case**. And it fails because the channel id does not exist.

When you set a correct channel id, the URL is also correct because the resource exists and therefore you get the desired results.

However, when you set a wrong channel id the HTTP request fails (because that URL does not exist). Regardless of this, **you are attempting to read the response and that's when it all blows up**.

When you make an HTTP request to a server, it responds with a **status code** indicating what happened with your request. You are completely ignoring this status code.

Look at the headers that a request to that URL throws using:

`curl -i https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/497971/feeds.json?results=1`:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Status: 400 Bad Request
... [Shortened] ...
```

You can learn all about HTTP status codes in a simple Google search but the summary is that it is a number between 100 and 599 that indicates:

- Request successfully handled: when it is between 200 and 299.
- Request could not be handled, it failed: when it is between 400 and 499.
- The request failed because the server basically blew up: (> 500).

In order to retrieve this status code, you need to call the `getResponseCode()` method of the `urlConnection` instance.

Only when the status code is successful (between 200 and 299) the call to `urlConnection.getInputStream()` will succeed. In case of error you need to call `urlConnection.getErrorStream()`.

So **in order to fix your code**, you need to do something like this:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    URL url;
    result = "";
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(urls[0]);
        // Open the conection
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        // Retrieve status code
        int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        // Determine whether the request was handled successfully or not
        boolean success = (statusCode >= 200) && (statusCode < 300);
        InputStream in;
        if(success) {
            // Read the response when request was handled successfully
            in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        } else {
            // Read the error stream when the request failed
            in = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
        }
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
        int data = reader.read();
        while (data != -1) {
            char current = (char) data;
            result += current;
            data = reader.read();
        }
        return result;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // Close the connection
        if(urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

First of all, don't forget to close the connection once you are done (I included the disconnection in the `finally {}` block).

If you debug or log that code, you will see that the status code you are receiving is 400. That is the HTTP status code for `Bad Request`, indicating that your request is not correct and you need to fix it. If you analyze the content of the `result` variable, you will see that the value equals to -1.

Therefore in the `onPostExecute` callback you should make sure the value is different than -1 before attempting to deserialize it, since otherwise it will blow up again.

You can **fix your `onPostExecute` callback** like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(result.equals(-1)) {
            // Do something else, show an error to the user indicating the channel id is wrong
        } else {
            // Since there is no error, you can proceed with the deserialization of the response
            search(result);
        }
    }
```

I hope it helps and that it was clear enough.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As you described you need to update your code like

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView a, b;
    String result = "";
    String field1,field2,field3;
    private int count = 0;
    int channelId=497970;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        a = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a);
        b = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.b);
        startCounter(channelId);

    }

    public void startCounter(int channelId){
        new CountDownTimer(100000, 10000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
                task.execute("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/"+channelId+"/feeds.json?results=1");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        }.start();
    }

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            URL url;
            result = "";
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                int data = reader.read();
                while (data != -1) {
                    char current = (char) data;
                    result += current;
                    data = reader.read();
                }
                return result;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                startCounter(channelId+1);
            }

            catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            search(result);
        }

        public void search(String result) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONObject fieldinfo = jsonObject.getJSONObject("channel");

                String ff1 =  fieldinfo.optString("field1","No Value");
                String ff2 = fieldinfo.optString("field2","No Value");

                JSONArray weatherInfo = jsonObject.getJSONArray("feeds");

                JSONObject legsobject = weatherInfo.getJSONObject(0);
                field1 = legsobject.getString("field1");
                field2 = legsobject.getString("field2");

                a.setText(ff1);

                c.setText(field1);

            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: actually channel is input from user And It can be any number

Comment: As it is a variable you can take it from user input too.